# What is difference between require(path) and require(path)() in node.js

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

In node.js projects I have seen require(path) as well as require(path)() what does extra paranthasis refers.
When should I use require(path) and require(path)()

Comment: () is for calling method in general programming.

Answer (score 1):

The `require()` statement returns the `module.exports` property from within the module that is being loaded.  What you do with that depends entirely on what the module set it to.

If the module set it to a function of some kind (often called a module constructor function), then it is natural to call it with `var something = require('xxx')(...);`

But, if the module just exports an object with properties on it, then it would actually be a programming error to try to call it.

So, it depends entirely upon what the module you are loading is exporting.

---

For example, when loading the file system module, it would just be:

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

The variable `fs` in this case is just an object (not a function) so you would not call it - you would just reference properties on it:

```
fs.rename(...)
```

---

Here's an example of a module exporting a constructor function that you would call with `()` after it:

```
// myRoutes.js
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get("/", function() {...});
    app.get("/login", function() {...});
}

// app.js

// other code that sets up the app object
// ....

// load a set of routes and pass the app object to the constructor
require('./myRoutes')(app);
```

And, here's an example of a module just exporting properties so you would not call the module itself:

```
// myRoutes.js
module.exports.init = function(app) {
    app.get("/", function() {...});
    app.get("/login", function() {...});
}

// export commonly used helper function
module.exports.checkPath = function(path) {
    // ....
}

// app.js

// other code that sets up the app object
// ....

// load a set of routes and then initialize the routes
var routeStuff = require('./myRoutes');
routeStuff.init(app);


if (routeStuff.checkPath(somePath)) {
    // ...
}
```